# formating date from controller not getting expected result

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I am converting a string to date by using the `angular-filter` through controller. it's not getting expected result.

when i use the same in `html` that works fine.

here is my filter :

```
angular.module("tcpApp")
.filter("formatDate", 

    function () {

        return function (digiDate) {

            if(!digiDate) return;

            var regex = /\d+/g;

            return digiDate.match(regex)[0];

        }

});
```

my controller.js :

```
//weekDate is : Date(1438635600000+0300)/ - which i sending to fitler

    var weekDate =  $filter('formatDate')(contractorInfo.WeekDate, 'dd-MMM-yyyy');

    console.log( weekDate ); --> 1438635600000...!?
```

but in the `html` i am getting properly as `4-Aug-2014`. how to handle the filter form controller?

what is wrong here?

Any one help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sending a **Date** object instead of a unix timestamp which you are doing currently:

```
var weekDate = new Date(contractorInfo.WeekDate);
weekDate =  $filter('formatDate')(weekDate, 'dd-MMM-yyyy');
```